# Crystal Report not updating correctly from ODBC DSN Database View

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

When I print my crystal report, it will not print the correct (most recent) database view.  To get it to print the correct one, i have to manually select "set datasource location" and then click on the tables i want and then click update.  If i don't it will keep printing the same old view over and over.

I do have the "verify on every print" option selected but it doesn't seem to work.

I am using VS2010 with the beta crystal reports for vs2010 and ODBC 5.1.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you mean. Has your database changed (e.g. replaced a table) or you mean that the actual data is not being replicated in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you have the Save Data with Report option enabled. Try opening the report in the report designer, and see whether there is a tick on the File menu next to the Save Data with Report option - if so, uncheck it, save the report and try again.

Comment: Thank you! In crystal reports for VS2010 the checkbox is on the top left corner of the main report preview.  

I really appreciate your help and I'm sure my supervisor and team members do too haha.